# How to add jqplot bubble chart axis label

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using jqplot bubble chart. I want to show label on x and y axis. I tried as mentioned here. But it seems it does not work with bubble chart.

http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/axisLabelsRotatedText.html

Also, highlighter plugin does not work with bubblechart ?

I am badly stuck. I really appreciate any help here.

Thanks,
Jigar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this Example

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/85K6K/10/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var arr = [[11, 123, 1236, "Acura"], [45, 92, 1067, "Alfa Romeo"],
        [24, 104, 1176, "AM General"], [50, 23, 610, "Aston Martin Lagonda"],
        [18, 17, 539, "Audi"], [7, 89, 864, "BMW"], [2, 13, 1026, "Bugatti"]];

    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart', [arr], {
        /*seriesDefaults:
           {

        },*/
        series: [

            { 
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                                 bubbleAlpha: 0.6,
                                 highlightAlpha: 0.8
                            },
                    shadow: true,
                    shadowAlpha: 0.05
            }],
        axesDefaults: {
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                  label: 'X axis Label'
            },
            yaxis: {
                autoscale: true,
                  label: 'Y axis label'
            }
        }
    });
});
```